# Wordpress Custom Pages or Something Else?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I am creating a website which is not a blog, and I am using wordpress for my CMS - in short I am not even using the wordpress loop.

The website will display graphs and data from someone else's API and such but I am stuck on what seems to be the right way to do this, and all the documentation I find is for blogs or very very vague.

I want to be able to create pages, using just an import statement not a custom template - since those seem to be for text only, and not the huge php, ajax, mysql backend I plan to slap behind these pages.

For example:

```
// index.php

<?php get_header(); ?>

// Some file, like index_content.php imported into here
<?php get_custom_page_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>


// about.php

<?php get_header(); ?>

// Some file, like about_content.php imported into here
<?php get_custom_page_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It seems very conflicting because if I just make a new `.php` file like I explain below, it detracts from the CMS all together. I just edit them myself without even logging into the admin panel, since I see nothing to manage those files for me without directly linking from my menu items or whatever. Why wouldn't I then just @include everything and get rid of Wordpress completely. I must be missing something here.

The long and short of it is, I have no idea how to structure this and from my attempts to research, no idea what I am looking for to answer this.

How do I go about creating the above scenario, or is it as simple as just creating a new `.php` file for each named page and `@including` what I want?

I don't want to get into bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can use WordPress default [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates). You'll have the files `page-index.php` and `page-about.php` and they will appear as templates in the attributes meta box.

**2)** Or you can rely in custom meta fields and boxes, making your own personal meta box just like the default Attributes. This is done with `add_meta_box`, `get_post_meta` and `update_post_meta`. Check the [following results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2badd_meta_box%20%2bget_post_meta%20%2bupdate_post_meta) in WordPress Answers.
But, long story short, even knowing how to use those, I prefer to use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to handle that, as it's a well maintained and feature rich plugin.

With a custom meta box in place, simply choose from a pre-configured dropdown list (`index`, `about`) and in your `page.php` theme file use:

```
global $post;
$include = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'include_file', true );
get_template_part( 'content', $include );
```

`include_file` is the custom field that contains the dropdown selection. And you handle it yourself with `update_post_meta` or in a field created with ACF.

[`get_template_path()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) is a bundled WP function and in this example will look for the file `example.com/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/content-index.php` or `example.com/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME/content-about.php`.

---

Method 1 is straight forward. Method 2 enables much more details to be fine-tuned. A combination of both can be used.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. In hindsight this seems overly complex and hand coding would be a lot easier, with some integration of a very simple custom CMS. I will probably use your approach for future projects though. +vote.