# WordPress custom page CSS

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have tried to do some self research and found these questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30524290/wordpress-loading-custom-css-on-index-php#30584415) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290648/wordpress-custom-pages-or-something-else#18291164) but none of them really solved my problem so I created a new one.

I tried to use `wp_enqueue_scripts` function to load specific CSS file into specific page, but somehow it always skips the condition and proceeds to the else condition. Here is my code;

```
function theme_script_enqueue() {
    if(is_page_template('index.php')) {
        wp_enqueue_style('indexstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/news.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_script('indexjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
        wp_enqueue_script('mainjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
    }
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_script_enqueue');
```

When I access `http://localhost:8888/wordpress/index.php` just to make sure, based on the condition, I expected the script to load `news.css` but instead it loaded `main.css` which they have some elements with different colors so I spotted instantly. I did do the switch CSS file between the condition and it always load the else condition when I tried to access `index.php`. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As described here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

> index.php — If no specific page templates are assigned or found, WordPress defaults back to using the theme’s index file to render pages.

So for my understanding index.php is a fallback and not a template. 
Also you have to describe your template file:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

Have you written that comment into your template file?

Comment: So I tried to changed from `is_page_template` to `is_page` and the target is still `index.php` but the script is still not using `news.css` into my `index.php`. Is there any way for me to load specific css file into `index.php` and separated them from others css file?